# Linear matrix inequality for nonlinear system

Tags: dynamical-systems, control-theory, nonlinear-system, linear-matrix-inequality

Considering the nonlinear control system:
$$ \dot{x}=Ax(t)+B\phi(y) $$
where
$$ \phi(.): \mathbb{R} \mapsto \mathbb{R} $$ is a scalar sector-bounded nonlinearity, viz
$$ \phi \in Sector[\alpha,\beta] $$

How would I begin to obtain linear matrix inequality conditions which guarantee stability of the networked system? And how can I do this on MATLAB?

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you

Edit1: Editing the question for clarity.

Comment: This is the so-called "Lur'e problem" and has been extensively studied for many decades. It is esay to find articles addressing this problem in the LMI setting. I guess there are typos in the post as the feedback term should not be depending on $u$, but on $y$, which is a function of the state $x$. The sector condition can be incorporated in the LMI using the S-procedure.

Comment: Thank you! This is how the problem was sent to me, and I assumed it was alright. So it should be dot(x)=Ax+Bphi(y)? Im currently struggling with obtaining the sector inequality for the given bounds as I've not seen examples with that type of sector.

Comment: Check e.g. https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://stanford.edu/class/ee363/lectures/nonlin-fdbk.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwjD-sDM_MX5AhU7hf0HHZuxBAgQFnoECAcQAQ&usg=AOvVaw1AfUgwMm5r8rDbIVfDIPDh

Comment: Any tips on the matlab implementation? For multiple nonlinearities in the document attached* Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to deal with such a problem. I will develop a simple one that relies on the use of a quadratic Lyapunov function and the use of the S-procedure.

Let us consider the case where $y=Cx$ where $y\in\mathbb{R}^m$ and consider the following sector condition

$$(\phi- K_1y)^T(K_2y-\phi)\ge0$$ for some $y,\phi\in\mathbb{R}^m$ where $K_1$ and $K_2$ are diagonal matrices such that $K_2-K_1$ has nonnegative entries.

It can be reformulated as
$$\begin{bmatrix}
x\\
\phi
\end{bmatrix}^T\begin{bmatrix}
-2C^TK_1^TK_2C & C^T(K_2-K_1)^T\\
\star & -2I
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
x\\
\phi
\end{bmatrix}\ge0$$
which holds for some $x\in\mathbb{R}^n,\ \phi\in\mathbb{R}^m$. Define the set

$$\mathcal{S}:=\left\{(x,\phi)\in\mathbb{R}^n\times\mathbb{R}^m:\begin{bmatrix}
x\\
\phi
\end{bmatrix}^T\begin{bmatrix}
-2C^TK_1^TK_2C & C^T(K_2-K_1)^T\\
\star & -2I
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
x\\
\phi
\end{bmatrix}\ge0\right\}$$

Consider now the Lyapunov function $V(x)=x^TPx$ whose derivative along the trajectories of the system is given by

$$\dot{V}(x,\phi) =\begin{bmatrix}
x\\
\phi
\end{bmatrix}^T\begin{bmatrix}
A^TP+PA & PB\\
\star & 0
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
x\\
\phi
\end{bmatrix}.$$ Invoking now the S-procedure, we have that $(x,\phi)\in\mathcal{S}$ implies that $\dot{V}(x,\phi)$ is negative definite if and only if there exist a scalar $\tau\ge0$ such that

$$\begin{bmatrix}
A^TP+PA & PB\\
\star & 0
\end{bmatrix}+\tau\begin{bmatrix}
-2C^TK_1^TK_2C & C^T(K_2-K_1)^T\\
\star & -2I
\end{bmatrix}$$

is negative definite. This condition is an LMI condition that can be checked using any semidefinite programming solvers such as SeDuMi using Matlab or Python.

Comment: I've tried to formulate an LMI, and have factors of 1/2 (as Ive used alpha=0 and beta=1 for the sector boundaries), is the factor of 2 included to simplify and make the final LMI 'prettier'? My LMI for multiple nonlinearities looks like: \begin{bmatrix} A'P+PA & PB+C'T(0.5I) \\ B'P+T(0.5I)C & -T \end{bmatrix} (using Boyd's LMI book and lecture 16 ppt)

Comment: @ananimeaddict_ Yes, your condition is correct. You can set $T=2\tau$ and you will get the condition I gave.

Comment: I've also attempted a MATLAB implementation of this now! Apologies for the repetition, thank you for your help and clarification. Has the cost function of this system (Lur'e system) been explored? I'd like to do some further reading as (weakly) non-linear systems is a new topic of interest. Thank you @KBS!

Comment: @ananimeaddict_ What do you mean by cost function here? There is no cost function here as this is just a feasibility problem. The Lur'e problem (1944) has been studied for more than 80 years using many different methods and is still studied now. So, there is a lot of information about it.

Comment: Cost control or quadratic cost functions is what I was thinking about. I'll get reading! Thank you again.

Comment: @ananimeaddict_ Those problems have been studied for sure.